# Link between all NP-complete problems

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete, decision-problems

I have heard a quiet large number of times that **"If a polynomial time algorithm for solving an NP-complete problem is made, that means all NP-complete problems are solvable in polynomial time"** How's this true? Is it that all NP-complete problems have a common link?

(For example)Just wondering that if the 0-1 knapsack problem is solved(in P time), how can it's Polynomial time algorithm have anything to do with the partition problem, provided that both are NP-complete?

Comment: By definition, an NP-complete problem is a NP problem to which any other NP problem can be reduced in polynomial time.

Comment: Polynomial time needs not to be efficient in practice. We can have a large degree or large coefficients. But if one NP-complete problem can be solvedn in polynomial time, all other can as well (but with unknown concrete efficiency)

Comment: The first problem which has to be proven to be NP-complete was SAT. The other NP-complete problems were shown to be reducable to this problem.

Comment: That's exactly my question as to HOW one NP-complete can be reduced to another? Can you give an example? As to me it seemed absurd that how can the 0-1 knapsack problem be reduced to the partition problem or vice versa, provided both are NP-complete , just can't digest the fact as to WHY is it by definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to reducing *any* NP problem (including NP-complete problems) to SAT is

1. Write a subroutine that checks the polynomially-sized certificate,
2. Convert that routine to a circuit, and
3. Flatten the circuit to CNF using [the usual
   methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation).

For example, to convert integer factorization to SAT, you would write a routine that multiplies two $n$-bit multipliers producing a 2$n$-bit result.  Convert the routine to a circuit, then convert the circuit to CNF.  Then add simple declarative CNF clauses that force the 2$n$ output variables of the circuit to match the bits of the integer that you want to factor.  The resulting CNF instance will be satisfiable only if a bit pattern for the two $n$-bit numbers exists that when multiplied together produces the 2$n$-bit number you want factored.  (If you want trivial solutions excluded then you also need to add two extra CNF clauses that demand the most significant $n$-1 bits of each multiplier are not all zero.)

A problem like SUBSET SUM is a bit more intricate.  You need to write $n$ routines, each of which returns a particular one of the $n$ integers of the problem set or zero depending on the setting of a parameter bit.  These routines feed input into another routine you wrote that sums all $n$ of its inputs and outputs the result.  Convert all this into a circuit whose inputs are the parameter bits and whose outputs are the result of the addition routine.  Convert the circuit to CNF.  Add declarative CNF clauses that force the output variables of the adder routine to match the bits of $k$, the number a solution must sum to.  The resulting CNF instance will be satisfiable only if there exists a bit pattern of the parameter bits selecting a subset of the problem set that sums up to $k$.

To show a reduction from SAT to some other problem, I'll copy an answer I gave on the CS stack which shows how to reduce 3-SAT to SUBSET SUM.  (See Richard Karp's seminal paper ["Reducibility Among Combinatorial Problems"](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eluca/cs172/karp.pdf) for many more reductions between NP-complete problems.)

The trick to the reduction is to use numbers to encode statements about the 3CNF formula, crafting those numbers in such a way that you can later make an arithmetic proposition about the numbers that is only true if the original 3CNF formula is satisfiable.  The reduction below is lifted directly from the [lecture notes](https://people.clarkson.edu/%7Ealexis/PCMI/Notes/lectureB07.pdf) found at [https://people.clarkson.edu/~alexis/PCMI/Notes/lectureB07.pdf](https://people.clarkson.edu/%7Ealexis/PCMI/Notes/lectureB07.pdf) .

> We reduce 3SAT to SUBSET-SUM. Consider a 3CNF formula with variables $x_1, . . . , x_n$ and clauses $c_1, . . . , c_r$.  For each variable $x_i$, we will have two numbers $y_i$ and $z_i$ in the list.  For each clause $c_j$, we will also have two numbers $s_j$ and $t_j$.  We define all of these numbers by specifying their base 10 representations.  The construction is best explained by an example and a picture.
>
> If the formula is $(x_1∨x_2∨\overline{x_3})∧(\overline{x_1}∨x_2∨\overline{x_3})$, then the base 10 representations of the numbers will look like this:
>
> \begin{array}{c|ccc|cc}
>  & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & c_1 & c_2 \\
> \hline
> y_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
> z_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
> y_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\
> z_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
> y_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
> z_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
> \hline
> s_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
> t_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
> s_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
> t_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
> \hline
> k & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
>
> The number $y_i$ corresponds to the positive occurrences of $x_i$ in the formula while the number $z_i$ corresponds to its negative occurrences.  It should be clear how to generalize this construction to an arbitrary 3CNF formula.  And the list of numbers can clearly be constructed in polynomial time.  We claim  that  a  subset  of  these  numbers  adds  to  exactly $k$ if  and  only  if  the  formula is satisfiable.  A key point is that the sum of the numbers can be done column by column,  independently,  because  carries  will  never  occur.

The $s$ value is crafted the same way for each clause; put a one in the digit position corresponding to that clause, and zeroes everywhere else.  The $t$ value will be the same as the $s$ value for each clause.

The $k$ value is always 1111... followed by 33333.... where the number of ones is the same as the number of distinct variables in the formula and the number of threes is the number of clauses in the formula.  Note that the required sum $k$ has a one in each digit position corresponding to the variables.  This means that any solution to the subset sum problem can include only encoded statements about either a positive instance of the variable or a negative instance in each clause, not both.  Note also that sum $k$ has a three in the digit position corresponding to each clause.  The $s$ and $t$ values for each clause will sum to two, but to complete the sum a third one will have to come from one of the $y$ or $z$ values.  All three ones could come from the $y$ and $z$ values, but the fact that $s$ and $t$ will only sum to two for any clause guarantees that any empty clause in the 3CNF formula forces the subset sum problem to become unsatisfiable.

The lesson you should take from all this is that when reducing one NP-complete problem to another the general procedure is to construct [gadgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadget_%28computer_science%29) in the target problem that mimic constraint features of the source problem and then use those gadgets to construct a target problem instance that has a solution only if the source problem instance has a solution.